# how to check in python, that a string contains only alphabets and hypen

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to filter medical words from general english words.
but most of the drugs name contains hypen in it.
pls suggest how to check in python, that a string contains only alphabets and hypen.

for example : anti-allergic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to check string is as below, remove '-' from string and check if remaining characters are all alphabets.

```
test_str = 'anti-allergic'
if test_str.replace('-','').isalpha():
    print('Valid string')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using regular expressions (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), where a (very quick and dirty) regex could ask for all letters, a to z (and A to Z), that has a hyphen in it.

`([a-zA-Z]+[-].+)`

Would match the following:

> suoad
>   ADDADA 
>   waeewrw 
>   omaeqweSADADSwu 
>   iraaief 
>   `anti-allergic`
>   `ANTI-ALLERGIC`
>   testtesttest

You can test this out yourself using https://pythex.org/.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: this expression is matching strings that compulsorily have alphabets and hypen in it. but rejecting strings that contains only alphabets. can we form regular expression such that , it satisfy both conditions.